# create more than one derived column in one component ADF

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

I have started using ADF. When creating new derived columns, I use the derived column functionality. Is it possible to use one instance of this component to create more than one new column or do I need to nest components sequentially, one per each new column?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hi boski, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple columns inside of a single Derived Column. You will find a + button to add additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to use one instance of this component to create more than one new column?**

Yes, it is. @Mark Kromer is correct. You can use one [DerivedColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to create more than one new columns:

[image]

You could click the **Inspect** to see the input(source) schema and output schema.

Input(source) schema:

[image]

Output schema:
[image]

**Do I need to nest components sequentially, one per each new column?**

To sum up, no, you don't need to to that. If you have any other concerns, please let us know.

Hope this helps.